# Java a* algorithm implementation issue

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra, a-star

I'm trying to code the A* algorithm using a self implemented PQ and Vector. It has verticies as junctions and edges as roads. I was able to correctly code the dijkstra algorithm however I needed to improve the performance.

Currently my algorithm breaks throwing a null pointer exception as commented in the code. I've been researching the algorithm for the past 5+ hours whilst trying to implement it. I don't fully understand the method of comparing paths as well as I did for the dijkstra implementation.

Here is my current code:

```
    private Vertex dijkstra (int start, int end)
{


    Vertex current;
    while (!(pqOpen.IsEmpty()))
    {
        current = pqOpen.GetNextItem();


        else
        {               
            for (int i = 0; i < current.neighbors.GetNoOfItems(); i++)
            {                                   
                if (hold != null && hold.neighbors.GetItem(i).fromid != hold.city)
                {
                    int x = 1;                        



                if (hold2 == null || hold.getTentativeDistance() < hold2.getTentativeDistance())
                {
                    hold2.from = hold; //throws null pointer here
                    hold2.setTentativeDistance(hold.getTentativeDistance());
                    hold2.setF(hold2.getTentativeDistance() + heuristic(hold2, endLoc));  
                    System.out.println(hold2.from.city);
                }  
            }
        }   
    }
    return null;
}

  private double heuristic(Vertex goal, Vertex next)
  {        
      return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((goal.x - next.x), 2) + Math.pow((goal.y - next.y), 2));
  }
```

I've got a feeling that I've totally misunderstood the pseudo code about half way down the algorithm but as of yet I haven't found a representation that I can wrap my head around - so could someone possibly take a look at my code and point out where and what I'm doing wrong?

Here is a link to the website I used for reference: http://wiki.gamegardens.com/Path_Finding_Tutorial#Pseudo-code_A.2A

I also tried the wikipedia one, but their methods confused me even more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Currently it does loop round a few times and stores some nodes, however they are incorrect.

### Edit:

I've reverted my code and attempted it a different way. I'm now using these pseudo-code examples to understand the algorithm. http://web.mit.edu/eranki/www/tutorials/search/ and http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html

On the first one, I think my code is correct until line 13 on the pseudo code. From that point I get confused about the term he uses 'position'.

The if statement that I commented out, is from my dijkstra algorithm. However I think the if statements in the pseudo code I meantioned earlier should be something similar to what the IF statements are.

Could anyone possibly help me understand line 13 in the pseudocode in relation to my code?

Comment: Read dijkstra at first place, the difference of a* from dijkstra is just an additional heuristic weight for the priority queue. I would say a* is an optimization for dijkstra.

Comment: In Java, method names should start with a lower case letter. Perhaps you would like to change your method names as described here. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Which part of the algorithm do you start to lose your confidence in understanding what is happening?
If you are looking for a more verbose explanation, you could give this a try. http://web.mit.edu/eranki/www/tutorials/search/

Comment: @Taekahn I'm currently looking at this pseudo-code: http://web.mit.edu/eranki/www/tutorials/search/ and it's on line 13 that I'm starting to get confused. I don't understand what it means by the 'a node with the same position as successor is in the OPEN list' by position what does it mean? PQ position? I'll edit the first post as I've reverted my code and tackled it a different way

Comment: @Taekahn I just realised that you linked me to the same page I was looking at! Sorry about that - I already had that link open last night before you had commented - decided to try and implement it this morning!

Comment: I believe line 13 and the following ones are referring to the ability of a node on the current path to connect not only to a node already on your "to be explored list", but also on your list of already explored nodes. But we only care about them if their cost is less than what we've already seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not read all the code, but this part is obviously bad :)

```
          if (hold2 == null)
            {
                hold2.from = hold; //throws null pointer here
            }
```

See? If the hold2 is null, you are trying to asign value to field `from` of hold2 which is **null** in this case, therefore it throws an exception.